# Convert multiple to column in excel or sql

Tags: mysql, excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyhVX.png)

my goal is to transoform the UOM and the qty for the given article to row [image: sample 1] how can I easily do that using excel or sql

Final Result should be a single row with the different uom and quantities

Comment: Please SHOW the final result you need, don't just describe it; [mre]

Comment: A pivot table would do the trick. Stick OUM in the columns, Articles in the Rows, and Qty in the Values. In Mysql you could use `SELECT article, SUM(CASE WHEN UOM='EA' THEN Qty END) as EA, SUM(CASE WHEN UOM='CS' THEN Qty End) as cs, SUM(CASE WHEN UOM='MP' THEN Qty END) as mp FROM yourtable GROUP BY article`

Comment: As an aside, if you edit your question again, please add 4-spaces to the start of each line of your example/desired results to maintain the formatting. You can also select the text and click the {} button at the top of the editor.

Comment: Thanks JN ill give it a shot and let you know the outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the case of PIVOT and unfortunately in mysql you don't have direct pivot function like in SQL Server. However, you can use CASE statements to achieve this.

```
Select     
  Article,
  SUM(Case When UOM='EA' THEN Qty Else NULL End) as EA,
  SUM(Case When UOM='CS' THEN Qty Else NULL End) as CS,
  SUM(Case When UOM='MP' THEN Qty Else NULL End) as MP
From (TABLE_NAME)
Group by Article
```

This should work for you.